# unterminated string literal when use a php echo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery to produce some text that is coming from my Database.

However I keep getting the jQuery error:

```
unterminated string literal
```

My code in raw format looks like :

```
                            + "<div class='operator-details'>"
                            + "<strong>Operator:</strong> Stuart"
                            + "<br />"
                            + "<br /><strong>Phone:</strong> 01"
                            + "<br />"
                            + "<br /><strong>Contact:</strong> <a href='#'>x@x.com</a>"
                                                        + "</div>"
                                                        + "<div class='featured-venue'>"
                            + "<p>Great venue to vistIt is a pleasure to feature it.</p>"
                            + "</div>"
```

The jQuery code is :

```
+ "<div class='operator-details'>"
                            + "<strong>Operator:</strong> <?php echo $venue->user_firstname; ?> <?php echo $venue->user_surname; ?>"
                            + "<br />"
                            + "<br /><strong>Phone:</strong> <?php echo $venue->user_telephone; ?>"
                            + "<br />"
                            + "<br /><strong>Contact:</strong> <a href='mailto:<?php echo $venue->user_email; ?>'><?php echo $venue->user_email; ?></a>"
                            <?php if($venue->venue_website) { ?>
                                + "<br />"
                                + "<br /><strong>Website:</strong> <a href='<?php echo $venue->venue_website; ?>' target='_blank'><?php echo $venue->venue_website; ?></a>"
                            <?php } ?>
                        + "</div>"
                        <?php if($venue->venue_featured == 'Yes') { ?>
                            + "<div class='featured-venue'>"
                            +   "<p><?php echo strip_tags($venue->venue_featured_text); ?></p>"
                            + "</div>"
                        <?php } ?>
```

Is there any way I can correct this error?

Thanks

Comment: is the tag `<script>` is part of the string?

Comment: Probably your php values contain `"` characters. Put them in `addslashes` or `mysql_real_escape_string` function to escape special chars.

Comment: Cheers @BatuZet thats worked a treat!

Comment: This gets asked every day. You have to use `json_encode()`; please find for any of the many dupes for further details.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario its nothing to do with json_encode it was " characters and required an mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)